# SimpleDateFormat глючит

Tags: java, android

SimpleDateFormat глючит

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                String d = sdf.format(new Date(1465837275));
                text2.setText(d);
```

Должно быть 21:01

А получаю.Что за хрень?
04:10

Comment: а вы где живете? =)

Comment: Екатеринбург.

Просто раньше проблем не было с этим, Месяца 4 назад когда кодил

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере используется конструктор даты из абсолютного времени (условно говоря время из зоны `+0000` или `GMT` начиная с `1 января 1970 00:00:00`). Но при преобразование в строковый формат временная зона не указана. Поэтому берется временная зона по умолчанию. Как можно увидеть из [онлайн конвертора](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm), то он вообще даёт 23:10, но при это указывает временную зону. Если тебе нужно 'правильное' время, то следует явно указывать временную зону при преобразовании. См. пример:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date = new Date(1465837275);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-5"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+2"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));

//обратный перевод с указанием выводить таймзону
SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
System.out.println(sdf3.format(date));
SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");
System.out.println(sdf4.format(date));
SimpleDateFormat sdf5 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS X");
System.out.println(sdf5.format(date));
```

Вывод консоли:

```
04:10
21:10
17.01.1970 20:10:37.275 BRT
17.01.1970 20:10:37.275 -0300
17.01.1970 20:10:37.275 -03
```

Подробности про шаблоны можно почитать в [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: date взят из VK. Гляньте [взял из VK](https://new.vk.com/dev/wall.get?params[owner_id]=-21314891&params[count]=3&params[filter]=owner&params[extended]=1&params[v]=5.52)

Comment: я мало пойму при чем здесь vk, но добавил пример в ответ

Comment: А как выглядит строка Date которая бы хранила в себе еще и зону?:

Comment: Тут всё зависит от шаблона. Обновлю ответ для разъяснений